# Mixed Linear Model - REML approach AI or FS algorithm

Tags: mixed-model, algorithms, fisher-information, reml

I am trying to see if there is a situation where Fisher scoring algorithm would be better than Average Information algorithm. I know that Average information algorithm is more efficient for large data sets because of the data computational issues Fisher Scoring algorithm has with big data sets but if your data set were reasonably sized to use Fisher scoring algorithm does it hold some sort of advantage over Average information algorithm?

Comment: Any info on how AI works would also be appreciated.

Comment: Why not implement REML estimation using AI and FS and then compare the two? For AI, you can refer to: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2533274?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents